# Remover Caracteres especiais Oracle

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Bom dia,

Tenho uma consulta aqui feita em Oracle onde em um dos registros está trazendo uma cadeia de caracteres começando com aspas, tem alguma função oracle para remover somente as aspas no começo e no final de uma string?

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com base na sua necessidade, elaborei uma função, e adicionei a possibilidade de você definir que caractere deseja remover do início e fim da string, espero que lhe ajude:

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_REMOVE_CARACTER_INICIO_FIM(P_STRING    IN VARCHAR,
                                                        P_CARACTERE IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '''')
  RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  RESULT   VARCHAR2(500);
  V_INICIO BOOLEAN := FALSE;
  V_FINAL  BOOLEAN := FALSE;
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--DESENVOLVEDOR::. RAPHAEL DE SOUZA GODOI
--DT. CRIAÇÃO::. 08/10/2018
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BEGIN

  IF INSTR(P_STRING, P_CARACTERE) = 1 THEN
    V_INICIO := TRUE;
  END IF;

  IF INSTR(P_STRING, P_CARACTERE, -1) = LENGTH(P_STRING) THEN
    V_FINAL := TRUE;
  END IF;

  IF (V_INICIO = TRUE AND V_FINAL = TRUE) THEN
  
    RESULT := SUBSTR(P_STRING, 2, LENGTH(P_STRING) - 2);
  
  ELSIF V_INICIO = TRUE AND V_FINAL = FALSE THEN
  
    RESULT := SUBSTR(P_STRING, 2, LENGTH(P_STRING));
  ELSIF V_FINAL = TRUE AND V_INICIO = FALSE THEN
    RESULT := SUBSTR(P_STRING, 1, LENGTH(P_STRING) - 1);
  ELSE
    RESULT := P_STRING;
  
  END IF;

  RETURN(RESULT);
END F_REMOVE_CARACTER_INICIO_FIM;
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer utilizando REGEX

```
 REGEXP_REPLACE ('"Teste"', '^("|'')|("|'')$', '')
```

onde ele substitui aspas simples ou dupla no inicio e/ou no final de seu campo.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm